# Execution error, return code 1 when trying to create an external table in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, flume, flume-twitter

I have searched and tried all solutions online and I seem to be getting the same error when trying to create an external table in hive:

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
> org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/SerDe

I am trying to create an external table, populating it with data I extracted from Twitter using Flume. My extracted data is located in hdfs storage system : `/user/hadoop/twitter_data`.

I did the following:

1. Downloaded `hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` from Cloudera.
2. Add jar `/home/hadoop/Desktop/Flume_cheat/twitter/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.
3. `create external table Twitter_Flume3 (id BIGINT,created_at STRING,source STRING,favorited BOOLEAN,retweet_count INT,retweeted_status STRUCT<text:STRING,user1:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,entities STRUCT<urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,user2_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,text STRING,user3 STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING,friends_count:INT,followers_count:INT,statuses_count:INT,verified:BOOLEAN,utc_offset:INT,time_zone:STRING>,in_reply_to_screen_name STRING) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe' LOCATION '/user/training/flume_result';`
4. `FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/SerDe`

**Version**

- Hadoop version 3.2.1
- Hive version 3.1.2

Comment: i can help you, let me review it!!

Comment: @KenrySanchez thats alot, please what would you want me to share with you